# The first line of input cannot be obtained

Tags: python, sys

I want to input this:

```py
2
1 5
10 20
```

to get to an array like this:

```py
[2]
[1, 5]
[10, 20]
```

but It always shows:

```py
[1, 5]
[10, 20]
```

Any help is appreciated!

```
import sys
n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
for i in range(n):
    listd=sys.stdin.readline()
    value=list(map(int,listd.split()))
    print(value)
```

Comment: Did you mean: ‘print([n])’ before the for loop?

Comment: @quamrana Sry,I have updated the code format

Comment: Perhaps you need to update the question again because your current code will not produce the format of output you claim.

Comment: @quamrana I updated an image. Plz click to see it

Comment: Ok, I shall indulge you just this once and edit your question to match the image you linked to. You should have been able to do this yourself. You may not like my edit, but then you could make your own correction.

Answer (score 0):

To literally get what you want you can just add a `print()` of the bit that is missing:

```py
import sys
n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
print([n])
for i in range(n):
    listd=sys.stdin.readline()
    value=list(map(int,listd.split()))
    print(value)
```